# Find if a string appear before another string

Tags: r, string, grepl

I have a string variable containing patients' addresses. My goal is to flag patients who live in "401 30th street". I would like to flags strings that contain the number "401" before "30" to avoid flagging addresses like number 3. My code below only flag whether the string contains the number 401 and 30 regardless of their positions. Any help would be appreciate it.

```
                      ADDRESS Outcome
1                401 300th st   FALSE
2             40120 30 street   FALSE
3                  30 401 plz    TRUE
4                 401 30th st    TRUE
5    401 e gibbsborro rd, 305   FALSE
6  401 e 30th street, shelter    TRUE
7               401 east 30st    TRUE
8         401 e30th street, 3    TRUE
9      77-02 30th ave, 3rd fl   FALSE
10                401 e30 st.    TRUE
```

```
structure(list(ADDRESS = c("401 300th st", "40120 30 street", 
"30 401 plz", "401 30th st", "401 e gibbsborro rd, 305", "401 e 30th street, shelter", 
"401 east 30st", "401 e30th street, 3", "77-02 30th ave, 3rd fl", 
"401 e30 st."), Outcome = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

```
loction <- location %>%
  mutate(ADDRESS = tolower(ADDRESS),
         st30 =  grepl("\\<401\\>", ADDRESS) & 
          grepl("\\<30\\>|\\<30th\\>|\\<30st\\>|\\<e30th\\>|\\<e30\\>", ADDRESS))
```

Edit: I added new observations to the sample data as well as the variable I am looking to generate. The idea is to flag patients from 401 30th Street. To do this I would like to flag strings that have the number 401 before 30|30th|s30|east30|e30st etc. I hope this clarifies what I am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need `location %>% mutate(flag = str_detect(ADDRESS, '401\\S*.*\\b30'))` i.e. do you flag `40120 30` as a valid one.  If it doesn't include that, `location %>% mutate(flag = str_detect(ADDRESS, '401\\b.*\\b30'))`

Comment: What is the final expected result?

Comment: Why not just `grepl("401.*\\b30[^0-9]?", ADDRESS)`? It appears that 401 and 40120 are both acceptable, but `30` must not be followed by another digit.

Comment: Try `location %>% mutate(st30 = str_detect(ADDRESS, '401.*30(?!\\d)'))` or `location %>% mutate(st30 = str_detect(ADDRESS, '401.*\\b30(?!\\d)'))`. Here, `401` matches even in `14012` but `30(?!\d)` won't match `301`, and `\b30(?!\d)` won't match in `1301`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I would like strings (true/false) that contains the number 401 before 30|30th|30st|e30th|e30. So in this case strings such as 40120 30 st or 30 401 street should not be flagged. I guess that is the best pattern to flag the real address "401 30th Street".

Comment: Like `401.*?e?30(?:th|st)?`? See https://regex101.com/r/6zv0Hf/1 You know, it is equal to `401.*?30` in this case (it is used in `grepl`). What are the expected results here?

Comment: Marvin, we still are not sure what strings you need to get, what result you want to see for your test cases.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I updated my post. Hopefully it clarifies what I am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: You can use ``grepl("^(?=.*\\b401\\b)(?=.*?\\be?30(?:th|st)?\\b)", ADDRESS, perl=TRUE)``

Comment: Did you have time to check it?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it is still not flagging addresses like 401 e30th st, 401 east 30th street, pvt, 401 e. 30th st, 33, etc. My original code flagged all these addresses. The only problem with my original code was addresses like" 600 30 st, apt 401 st."

Comment: My regex [matches](https://regex101.com/r/NmqpVK/2) these strings.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry for the confusion. The code worked perfectly. Thanks a lot! Marvin

Comment: Done- thank you for the explanations as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address the updated question, you need to use

```r
grepl("^(?=.*\\b401\\b)(?=.*?\\be?30(?:th|st)?\\b)", ADDRESS, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NmqpVK/1/) and the [R demo](https://ideone.com/o3cO72). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*\b401\b)` - there must be `401` whole word somewhere after any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `(?=.*?\be?30(?:th|st)?\b)` - there must be a word boundary, an optional `e`, `30`, then an optional `th` or `st` char sequence and a word boundary somewhere after any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible

---

When you use two separate `grepl` calls, the matches are searched for irrespective of the order of their appearance in the string.

**Maching two substrings in order** means

- Matching the leftmost pattern
- *Matching any chars* (because the regex engine must somehow get to the second pattern) with a pattern like `.*`, `.*?`, `[\s\S]*?`, `(?s:.)*?` (the latter two are PCRE/ICU compliant), etc.
- Matching the rightmost pattern.

So, here, as there are no line breaks in the input, you could probably use

```r
df %>%
    mutate(st30 = grepl('401.*?30', ADDRESS))
```

**However**, `401` and `30` patterns above are matching in any context. If you want to match them as exact integer values, you need to use *numeric* boundaries:

```r
grepl('(?<!\\d)401(?!\\d).*?(?<!\\d)30(?!\\d)', ADDRESS, perl=TRUE)
```

Probably, you can also get away with simple word boundaries at the start of these numeric patterns (i.e. before them, no letter, digit or underscore are allowed):

```r
grepl('\\b401(?!\\d).*?\\b30(?!\\d)', ADDRESS, perl=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
location %>%
    mutate(flag = str_detect(ADDRESS, '401\\b.*\\b30'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
location %>% 
    mutate(flag = str_detect(ADDRESS, '^[^30]*401 .*30.*$'))
```

output:

```
          ADDRESS  flag
1     401 30th st  TRUE
2 40120 30 street FALSE
3       30 401 st FALSE
4     401 30th st  TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for the reply. However, addresses like  
"401 e 30th st" are being flagged. Can we modify your code and an "or" statement such as "30|30th|30st|e30th|e30". Also addresses like "401 e. 30 st, 831", "400 e 30 st" are not getting flagged.  Perhaps because "30" is not at the end of the string?

Comment: But "401 e 30th st" fullfills your condition `401` before `30`. Therefore it should be flagged?